# Search By Word Not Charecter

Tags: javascript, search

I want my serach function when user stop typing, because when typing the search is being performed for each charecter. For that issue search is taking so much time. So I want when user stop typing then search function will start. My current search code:

```
function search(){
            var searchKey = $('#search').val();
            if(searchKey.length > 3){
                $('body').addClass("typed-search-box-shown");

                $('.typed-search-box').removeClass('d-none');
                $('.search-preloader').removeClass('d-none');
                $.post('{{ route('search.ajax') }}', { _token: AIZ.data.csrf, search:searchKey}, function(data){
                    if(data == '0'){
                        // $('.typed-search-box').addClass('d-none');
                        $('#search-content').html(null);
                        $('.typed-search-box .search-nothing').removeClass('d-none').html('Sorry, nothing found for <strong>"'+searchKey+'"</strong>');
                        $('.search-preloader').addClass('d-none');

                    }
                    else{
                        $('.typed-search-box .search-nothing').addClass('d-none').html(null);
                        $('#search-content').html(data);
                        $('.search-preloader').addClass('d-none');
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                $('.typed-search-box').addClass('d-none');
                $('body').removeClass("typed-search-box-shown");
            }
        }
```

Comment: It's called debouncing, look it up. You can easily implement a debouncing mechanism with a simple `setTimeout()`

Comment: Also not sure what `$.post('{{ route('search.ajax') }}'` is supposed to be, it's a syntax error. But even by writing `$.post('{{ route(' + search.ajax + ') }}'` the output doesn't really make sense

Answer (score 0):

Here's a debounced (and rewritten, with jQuery objects cached, `async/await` instead of a callback function, etc.) version of your search function.

Basically on keyUp you call `searchDebounced()`, which will then call the actual `search()` 500ms later, unless a new key is pressed, which resets the timeout and waits an additional 500ms :

```
const $search = $('#search'),
    $searchContent = $('#search-content'),
    $body = $("body"),
    $typedSearchBox = $('.typed-search-box'),
    $searchPreloader = $('.search-preloader'),
    $searchNothing = $('.typed-search-box .search-nothing');

let debounceTimeout = null

function searchDebounced() {
    
    const searchKey = $search.val().trim();
    
    if (searchKey.length < 4) {
        $typedSearchBox.addClass('d-none');
        $body.removeClass("typed-search-box-shown");
        return;
    }

    // These two lines do the debouncing work
    clearTimeout(debounceTimeout);
    debounceTimeout = setTimeout( search, 500 );
}

async function search() {

    $body.addClass("typed-search-box-shown");
    $typedSearchBox.removeClass('d-none');
    $searchPreloader.removeClass('d-none');

    const data = await $.post('{{ route(' + search.ajax + ') }}', { // No idea what this route is, I'm assuming it makes sense somehow
        _token: AIZ.data.csrf,
        search: searchKey
    })

    if (data == '0') {
        $searchContent.html(null);
        $searchNothing.removeClass('d-none').html('Sorry, nothing found for <strong>"' + searchKey + '"</strong>');
    } else {
        $searchContent.html(data);
        $searchNothing.addClass('d-none').html(null);
    }
    $searchPreloader.addClass('d-none');
}
```